# How do we work with polkadot-js enums in TypeScript?

Tags: polkadot-js, scale-codec, contracts, typescript

I used [typegen](https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs/tree/master/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen) to generate my types from definitions.

### Definition

```
        Person: {
            status: 'Status',
            balance: 'u128',

        },
        Status: {
            _enum: ['Active', 'Suspended', 'Deactivated'],
        },
```

### Generated types

```
/** @name Status */
export interface Status extends Enum {
  readonly isActive: boolean;
  readonly isSuspended: boolean;
  readonly isDeactivated: boolean;
  readonly type: 'Active' | 'Suspended' | 'Deactivated';
}

/** @name Person */
export interface Person extends Struct {
  readonly status: Status;
  readonly balance: u128;
}
```

Note that the `enum` type has fields `isActive`, `isSuspended`, `isDeactivated`.
`

### Decoding my type

I created a function in my contract that returns `Result<Person, Error>` I decode this result in JS.

```
const decoded = this.contract.api.registry.createType(`Result<Person, Error>`, result.data.toU8a(true))
if (decoded.isOk) {
    return decoded.asOk.toPrimitive()
```

This is where my problem starts. The `toPrimitive` function (and `toJSON`, `toHuman`, etc.) does not output the `isActive`, `isSuspended`, and `isDeactivated` fields of my `Status` enum. They are `undefined`.

How do I access the `isActive`, `isSuspended`, and `isDeactivated` fields after decoding my type?

Answer (score 3):

Not able to reproduce your problem, but by looking at the code i am thinking it should be something like this:

```
if (result.isOk) {
  const decoded = this.contract.abi.registry.createType(`Result<Person, Error>`, [result.asOk.data]).toHuman()
}
console.log(decoded.isActive)
```